# Importing key value into foreach Take() to limit list items C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the following foreach loop in a c# project which loops through list items and it limits it to only show 3

And in my

What I need to do is replace th in the key instead.

I'm guessing it's meant to be

Comment: can you take one int variable and then get the config value into that variable and pass that variable to your Take() ?

Answer (score 3):

To access App/Web.config you can use `ConfigurationManager`:

```
int value = (int)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TrendingNavLimit"];
```

Please follow that article for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

If we put it all together, solution could be:

```
int value = (int)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TrendingNavLimit"];
foreach (NavigationItem item in items.Take(value))
{
    @NavigationHelper.SimpleNavLink(config, item, absoluteUrls);
}
```

---

In terms of SOLID, I would re-thing approach though.

I would create an `interface` -  `IConfigProvider` with property `TrendingNavLimit {get;}` and implement that `interface` in default class, that will use `ConfigurationManager` to retrieve data, and then inject it in you class.

Comment: this is what I mean in the question comment

Comment: Thanks, when I try that and try to publish the project I get the error "The name configurationManager does not exist in the current context"

Comment: use full namespace or add `using System.Configuration;` on top of your class. In C# configurationManager is not same as ConfigurationManager. You may be missing a reference as well, make sure you have reference to System.Configuration in your project.